# How to integrate Hashi corp vault on two instances which are in two different availability zones and make them to use the same backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, hashicorp-vault

I have two instances which run vault on two different availability zones. Now I want to integrate them and make them use the same backend.

I know there is a vault enterprise version for this. But, I want a open source way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If both point to same `storage`, then they both will have same backend.
For example, if they both have following `storage` setup, then they both will read or write data in S3 `my-bucket`

```
storage "s3" {
  access_key = "abcd1234"
  secret_key = "defg5678"
  bucket     = "my-bucket"
}
```